# How can I replace an item in a list with a string that has a space in it?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, replace

I am trying to simply replace a list item with another item, except the new item has a space in it. When it replaces, it creates two list items when I only want one. How can I make it just one item in the list please?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import re

cont = "BECMG 2622/2700 32010KT CAVOK"
actual = "BECMG 2622"
sorted_fm_becmg = ['BECMG 262200', '272100']
line_to_print = 'BECMG 262200'

becmg = re.search(r'%s[/]\d\d\d\d' % re.escape(actual), cont).group()
new_becmg = "BECMG " + becmg[-4:] + "00" # i need to make this one list item when it replaces 'line_to_print'
sorted_fm_becmg = (' '.join(sorted_fm_becmg).replace(line_to_print, new_becmg)).split()

print(sorted_fm_becmg)
```

I need `sorted_fm_becmg` to look like this : `['BECMG 270000', '272100']`.

I've tried making `new_becmg` a list item, I have tried removing the space in the string in `new_becmg` but I need the list item to have a space in it.
It is probably something simple but I can't get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through `sorted_fm_becmg` to replace each string individually instead:

```
sorted_fm_becmg = [b.replace(line_to_print, new_becmg) for b in sorted_fm_becmg]
```